# Examine Variables Equivalent in R?

Tags: r, spss

As a former SPSS user I was wondering if anybody knows of an equivalent to the 'examine' command in R? E.g.:

```
EXAMINE VARIABLES=income by sex
 /CINTERVAL 95.
```

Cheers

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly does this return (for us R users who don't use SPSS)?

Answer (score 1):

The closest I'm aware of is the `describe` function found in the `psych` package.

Here's some code you can run to see how it works:

```
install.packages('psych')
library(psych)
data('mtcars')

# Standard describe function
describe(mtcars$mpg)

# Show interquartile ranges
describe(mtcars$mpg, IQR = TRUE)
```

The output for `describe(mtcars$mpg, IQR = TRUE)`:

```
   vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se  IQR
X1    1 32 20.09 6.03   19.2    19.7 5.41 10.4 33.9  23.5 0.61    -0.37 1.07 7.38
```

Answer (score 1):

One can also handle a level of by group processing by adding `split()` and `lapply()` to Matt's answer.  For example, to obtain descriptive statistics on `mtcars$mpg` by number of cylinders, we do the following:

```
library(psych)
splitvar <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
data <- split(mtcars,splitvar)
lapply(data,function(x){describe(x$mpg,IQR=TRUE)})
```

...and the output:

```
> lapply(data,function(x){describe(x$mpg,IQR=TRUE)})
$`4`
   vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se IQR
X1    1 11 26.66 4.51     26   26.44 6.52 21.4 33.9  12.5 0.26    -1.65 1.36 7.6

$`6`
   vars n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range  skew kurtosis   se  IQR
X1    1 7 19.74 1.45   19.7   19.74 1.93 17.8 21.4   3.6 -0.16    -1.91 0.55 2.35

$`8`
   vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range  skew kurtosis   se  IQR
X1    1 14 15.1 2.56   15.2   15.15 1.56 10.4 19.2   8.8 -0.36    -0.57 0.68 1.85

>
```

We can also add quantiles via the `quant=` argument. Here we'll generate the 5%ile and 95%ile values.

```
lapply(data,function(x){describe(x$mpg,quant=c(.05,.95),IQR=TRUE)})
```

...and the output:

```
> lapply(data,function(x){describe(x$mpg,quant=c(.05,.95),IQR=TRUE)})
$`4`
  vars  n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range skew kurtosis   se IQR Q0.05 Q0.95
1    1 11 26.66 4.51     26   26.44 6.52 21.4 33.9  12.5 0.26    -1.65 1.36 7.6 21.45 33.15

$`6`
  vars n  mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range  skew kurtosis   se  IQR Q0.05 Q0.95
1    1 7 19.74 1.45   19.7   19.74 1.93 17.8 21.4   3.6 -0.16    -1.91 0.55 2.35 17.89 21.28

$`8`
  vars  n mean   sd median trimmed  mad  min  max range  skew kurtosis   se  IQR Q0.05 Q0.95
1    1 14 15.1 2.56   15.2   15.15 1.56 10.4 19.2   8.8 -0.36    -0.57 0.68 1.85  10.4 18.88

>
```

...posting as Community wiki to avoid taking credit for Matt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `psych` package has a separate function, `describeBy()` that allows one to have multiple by group variables, which more closely emulates the behavior of the SPSS `EXAMINE` procedure.

We'll demonstrate with the `mtcars` data frame, using the `cyl` and `am` columns as by groups.

```
library(psych)
describeBy(mtcars,group = c("cyl","am"),quant=c(.05,.95))
```

...and the output for the first two by group combinations:

```
Descriptive statistics by group 
cyl: 4
am: 0
     vars n   mean    sd median trimmed  mad    min    max range  skew kurtosis    se  Q0.05
mpg     1 3  22.90  1.45  22.80   22.90 1.93  21.50  24.40  2.90  0.07    -2.33  0.84  21.63
cyl     2 3   4.00  0.00   4.00    4.00 0.00   4.00   4.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   4.00
disp    3 3 135.87 13.97 140.80  135.87 8.75 120.10 146.70 26.60 -0.31    -2.33  8.07 122.17
hp      4 3  84.67 19.66  95.00   84.67 2.97  62.00  97.00 35.00 -0.38    -2.33 11.35  65.30
drat    5 3   3.77  0.13   3.70    3.77 0.01   3.69   3.92  0.23  0.38    -2.33  0.08   3.69
wt      6 3   2.94  0.41   3.15    2.94 0.06   2.46   3.19  0.73 -0.38    -2.33  0.24   2.53
qsec    7 3  20.97  1.67  20.01   20.97 0.01  20.00  22.90  2.90  0.38    -2.33  0.97  20.00
vs      8 3   1.00  0.00   1.00    1.00 0.00   1.00   1.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   1.00
am      9 3   0.00  0.00   0.00    0.00 0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   0.00
gear   10 3   3.67  0.58   4.00    3.67 0.00   3.00   4.00  1.00 -0.38    -2.33  0.33   3.10
carb   11 3   1.67  0.58   2.00    1.67 0.00   1.00   2.00  1.00 -0.38    -2.33  0.33   1.10
      Q0.95
mpg   24.24
cyl    4.00
disp 146.11
hp    96.80
drat   3.90
wt     3.19
qsec  22.61
vs     1.00
am     0.00
gear   4.00
carb   2.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
cyl: 6
am: 0
     vars n   mean    sd median trimmed   mad    min    max range  skew kurtosis    se  Q0.05
mpg     1 4  19.12  1.63  18.65   19.12  1.04  17.80  21.40  3.60  0.48    -1.91  0.82  17.85
cyl     2 4   6.00  0.00   6.00    6.00  0.00   6.00   6.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   6.00
disp    3 4 204.55 44.74 196.30  204.55 42.55 167.60 258.00 90.40  0.17    -2.25 22.37 167.60
hp      4 4 115.25  9.18 116.50  115.25  9.64 105.00 123.00 18.00 -0.09    -2.33  4.59 105.75
drat    5 4   3.42  0.59   3.50    3.42  0.62   2.76   3.92  1.16 -0.09    -2.33  0.30   2.81
wt      6 4   3.39  0.12   3.44    3.39  0.01   3.21   3.46  0.25 -0.73    -1.70  0.06   3.25
qsec    7 4  19.21  0.82  19.17   19.21  0.85  18.30  20.22  1.92  0.11    -2.02  0.41  18.39
vs      8 4   1.00  0.00   1.00    1.00  0.00   1.00   1.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   1.00
am      9 4   0.00  0.00   0.00    0.00  0.00   0.00   0.00  0.00   NaN      NaN  0.00   0.00
gear   10 4   3.50  0.58   3.50    3.50  0.74   3.00   4.00  1.00  0.00    -2.44  0.29   3.00
carb   11 4   2.50  1.73   2.50    2.50  2.22   1.00   4.00  3.00  0.00    -2.44  0.87   1.00
      Q0.95
mpg   21.07
cyl    6.00
disp 253.05
hp   123.00
drat   3.92
wt     3.46
qsec  20.10
vs     1.00
am     0.00
gear   4.00
carb   4.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```